# Workflows and Forms for External Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, external-users

I'm working on collecting a series of workflows which need to be created to meet business needs throughout the functional areas of the company where I work. There are a few of these so far which would make sense to present to our employees which do not have Microsoft Logins.

Is there a way to open a Form (created in InfoPath) and the workflow associated with submitting this form to users without a MicroSoft Login?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use workflow to end the form to external users in SharePoint Online? If that’s the case, when the external users want to access a SharePoint Online file, we need to enable external sharing and send the guest link to the external users. You can check the articles: [SharePoint Online: How To Grant Anonymous Access To Site Collection Or Site Page] [SharePoint Online: How To Grant Anonymous Access To Site Collection Or Site Page]:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37346.sharepoint-online-how-to-grant-anonymous-access-to-site-collection-or-site-page.

Comment: No, Users need to be able to actually open the form and add a record to the list (as well as init the workflow).